# Excel Formula: Conditional Format if additional values are present

Tags: excel, logic, conditional-statements, formula, conditional-formatting

Here is what i need to achieve:

I want to change the format of a cell if it consists of a value other than Administrator or Authenticated User.
If it contains both Administrator and Authenticated user, the format is not changed.
However if it contains anomalies, such as "Everyone" or "Backup Operators" the cell is flagged. 
Basically if the cell contains anything other than Administrator or Authenticated User, the cell's format is changed.

Examples:

```
Administrator, Authenticated User           - Format Unchanged
Administrator                               - Format Unchanged
Authenticated User                          - Format Unchanged
Administrator, Authenticated User, Everyone - Format Changed
Everyone                                    - Format Changed
```

I have tried multiple methods to solve this, but they don't seem to be working. I use formulas to determine the cell formatting under Conditional Formatting.

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Admin","CELL"))), NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Auth","CELL"))))

=NOT(OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Admin",F132))), NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Auth",F132)))))
```

Now I am stuck and I have no idea how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think he means, it can have one or both of the values and format should not change. However if it has anything other then either, no matter what, it should change.

Comment: It took me a second as well ;) I put in an edit that might make it easier to read

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your input! I appreciate the help. Ben's answer is the best fit for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by @user2140261 works great. However, if you want a more dynamic solution where you don't have to add all the possibilities that it could be other than "Administrator" and "Authenticated User" then you could try this formula

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Administrator",""),"Authenticated User",""),", ",""),"ANOTHER NAME HERE", ""))>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Breaking down that formula from the inside out

- You use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace any occurrences of Administrator with "" in your source cell
- You use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace any occurrences of Authenticated User with "" in the result above
- You use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace any occurrences of ", " with "" in the result above
- You use `LEN` to test the length of the result above, if it's greater than 0 then something other than Administrator or Authenticated User is in the cell.

Which results in

```
Administrator, Authenticated User              FALSE
Authenticated User                             FALSE
Authenticated User, Administrator              FALSE
Authenticated User, Administrator, Everyone    TRUE
Everyone                                       TRUE
```

Where when it's true it means that the format needs to change.

**edit**
To account for you wanting to add/remove more values now and to be able to customize it easily, it might be easiest to do a UDF:

```
Public Function SUBSTITUTEARRAY(ByVal Source As Range, ByVal Substitute As Range) As String

    Dim c       As Range
    Dim rtn     As String

    rtn = Source.Value

    For Each c In Substitute.Cells
        rtn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rtn, c.Value, "")
    Next c

    SUBSTITUTEARRAY = rtn

End Function
```

Which you would call with: `=SUBSTITUTEARRAY(A1, F1:F5)` where A is the source cell that you want to check and F1:F5 contains the values you want to check for ("Administrator", "Authenticated User" etc...)

It will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether or not there are other values then those in the cell.

Comment: Hi Ben, what if i need to add more users than just Administrator and Authenticated Users? I have been trying to add in another nested substitute but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You would add it to the inside of the `LEN` function using the first `SUBSTITUTE` function as the `[text]` parameter. I've updated my answer to give you an idea. This also makes me wonder if there's a way to do this with one substitute function and the use of an array formula.

Comment: Ok so I looked into the possibility of this with an array formula. From what I researched it doesn't look like `SUBSTITUTE` works with arrays. But if you wanted to write your own user defined function that could probably simplify having to account for adding/removing names.

Comment: Hi Ben, your answers have been very insightful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add as many names as you want to be highlighted if the cell contains, just use text contains:

[image]

[image]